# Python pandas como mostrar el registro agrupado con count y max

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un dataframe de 3 columnas al cual agrupo por dos columnas, cuento y obtengo el máximo:

```
import pandas as pd

tabla = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"col1": ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
                                "col2": ['x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'z'],
                                "col3": ['alfa', 'beta', 'alfa', 'beta', 'alfa', 'alfa']})
print("mostrar tabla")
print(tabla)
print("agrupar por las primeras dos cols y contar los registros")
print(tabla.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).count())
print("buscar el "count" máximo")
print(tabla.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).count().agg(['max']))
print("mostrar el registro")
print(tabla.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).count().sort_values('col3').groupby(level=0).tail(1).iloc[[-1]])

**mostrar tabla
  col1 col2  col3
0    A    x  alfa
1    B    x  beta
2    C    x  alfa
3    A    y  beta
4    A    y  alfa
5    B    z  alfa

agrupar por las primeras dos cols y contar los registros
               col3
col1 col2      
A    x        1
     y        2
B    x        1
     z        1
C    x        1

buscar el 'count' máximo
     col3
max     2

mostrar el registro
           col3
col1 col2      
A    y        2**
```

Lo que quiero saber es si hay una manera MENOS abstrusa de "mostrar el registro" que hacer:

print(tabla.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).count().sort_values('col3').groupby(level=0).tail(1).iloc[[-1]])

col1 col2     col3

A    y        2    <<<=== resultado que busco

Y, por otra parte, para obtener los tres valores en respectivas variables hago:

```
dicc = tabla.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).count().sort_values('col3').groupby(level=0).tail(1).iloc[[-1]].to_dict()
print("\nEl máximo se da en la siguiente condición:\n")
for k in dicc['col3'].keys():
    print(f"col1 = {k[0]}")
    print(f"col2 = {k[1]}")
    print(f"count = {dicc['col3'][k]}")
```

lo cual, me parece, es complicarla demasiado ¿Hay una manera más directa/sencilla?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [`pandas.DataFrame.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) para obtener la fila con la cuenta máxima. Para asignar los tres valores a variables simplemente resetea el indice y desempaqueta los valores de la fila:

```
var1, var2, var_max = (tabla
                       .groupby(['col1', 'col2'])
                       .count()
                       .nlargest(1, "col3", "last")
                       .reset_index().values[0])
```